# Functions $f$ which satisfy $f(x^4+2x^2+2)-1=(f(x)-1)^4+4x(f(x)-1)^2+4x^2$

Tags: functional-equations

I want to find all functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which satisfy 
$$f(x^4+2x^2+2)-1=(f(x)-1)^4+4x(f(x)-1)^2+4x^2$$
for all $x$.

I know the solution: the only solution is $f(x)=x$. How can I prove it?

Comment: If you know the solution why don't you just plug it in and show the equality of both sides?

Comment: @SirJective yes, but how to show that f(x)=x is the only the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

More hypotheses are needed to ensure a unique solution, perhaps the OP meant to assume continuity.

Call $g(x) = f(x) - 1$. The functional equation is:
$$g\circ p(x) = (g(x)^2 + 2x)^2$$
for $p(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 + 2$. Since the image of $p(x)$ is $[2,\infty)$ and the expression containing $g(x)$ on the right hand side is squared, you can safely modify the values of $g$ on the domain $(-\infty, 2)$ by a minus sign while preserving the equation.